# Product on cellular cochains of the real Grassmannian

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, grassmannians

The real Grassmannian $Gr(k,n)$ of $k$-planes in $\Bbb R^n$ admits a Schubert cell decomposition, with one cell for each [Young diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau#Diagrams) $\lambda$ of height $\leq k$ and width $\leq (n-k)$; the dimension of the cell is the size $|\lambda|$ of the diagram.

After making a choice of orientation of each Schubert cell, one obtains a cellular cochain complex computing the cohomology of the Grassmannian, with one generator $e^\lambda$ in degree $|\lambda|$ for each Young diagram $\lambda$ as above. This has a coboundary formula
$$
\delta e^\lambda = \sum_{\mu} a_\mu^\lambda e^\mu.
$$
Here the sum is over Young diagrams $\mu$ with size $|\mu| = |\lambda|+1$ that contain $\lambda$, obtained by adding a single box $s$. One choice of orientation, for example, comes from a standard ordering of the coordinates in the Schubert cell / boxes in the Young diagram, and gives a formula where (if I have not miscalculated orientation)
$$
a_\mu^\lambda = (-1)^{r+1} (1 + (-1)^h).
$$
Here $h$ is the hook length of the box $s$ and $r$ is the total number of boxes whose column is strictly greater than the column where $s$ appears (counted equivalently in $\lambda$ or $\mu$).

The complex Grassmannian has cohomology whose set of generators is similarly a set of elements $e^\lambda$, but in degree $2|\lambda|$, and the product of this generators is
$$
e^\lambda \cup e^\mu = \sum c^{\lambda,\mu}_\rho e^\rho
$$
where the coefficients are [Littlewood-Richardson numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%E2%80%93Richardson_rule). The cohomology of the real Grassmannian is more complicated because of the nonzero cellular differential, but the cellular cochain complex is very similar.

Does there exist a product on the Schubert-cellular cochain complex of the real Grassmannian, making it a differential graded algebra that computes the cup product in cohomology, whose coefficients are (probably up to sign) the Littlewood-Richardson coefficients?

Comment: (On reflection, there is also the strong possibility that the appropriate rule involves something like a _signed_ count of skew tableaux.)